# Why does my code only print nil once?

Tags: lua, null, return-value, user-defined-functions

It's super-easy to fix; simply make it `return nil`, but **why** doesn't my code work without that line?

```
function x(bool)
    if bool then
        return "!"
    end
end

print(x(true), x(false), x(false))
```

What makes it even more confusing, is that always prints the `nil`, as many times as I call `x(false)` subtract 1.

I can't seem to wrap my ahead around why this is happening.

Comment: Number of values returned by a function call BEFORE COMMA is adjusted to one, number of values of last call is not adjusted.  So, you have `1+1+0` values printed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11) says:

> If control reaches the end of a function without encountering a `return` statement, then the function returns with no results.

Note that returning no result is different from returning `nil`.

---

In this call:

```
print(x(true), x(false), x(false))
```

both `x(false)` returns nothing, however,  all except the last element are always adjusted to exactly one result.

Usually we see functions call that return one or more results are left with only the first. Here *no result* is filled with a `nil` as well.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't just print "!" Then? And why not 2 nils?

Comment: @warspyking, as @YuHao said, the last function doesn't print `nil`, because it doesn't return `nil` (it returns nothing instead). The result from the second to last function is shown as `nil`, because even though it returns nothing (same as the last function), the result is *adjusted* to `nil` to keep the correct number of results. Change this to `x(true), x(false), 1`; you'd want the result to be `"!", nil, 1` and not `"!", 1`, right?

Comment: @Paul I suppose that's true, but if it wants to "keep the correct number of results" why doesn't the last one adjust?

Comment: Because it makes no difference in that case, but with the second to last it does make difference.